# How to auto delete a zip file after using stream_get_contents(); to view a file in php?

Tags: php

I have this code to read a file for preview, but the downside is I have to download the file first from cloud and read from it, but it's a waste of space so I want to delete it after viewing a certain file. Is there an automatic way of doing this? Or do I have to integrate it to a close button?

```
// Get the container we want to use
$container = $conn->get_container('mailtemplate');
//$filename = 'template1.zip';
// upload file to Rackspace
$object = $container->get_object($filename);
//var_dump($object);
//echo '<pre>' . print_r($object,true) . '</pre>';
$localfile = $dir.$filename;
//echo $localfile;
$object->save_to_filename($localfile);
    if($_GET['preview'] == "true")
    {
        $dir = "../mailtemplates/";
        $file1 = $_GET['tfilename'];
        $file = $dir.$file1;
        $file2 = "index.html";
        $info = pathinfo($file);
        $file_name =  basename($file,'.'.$info['extension']);
        $path = $file_name.'/'.$file2;
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip->open($file);
        $fp = $zip->getStream($path);
        if(!$fp)
        {
            exit("faileds\n");
            $zip->close();
            unlink($dir.$filename);                 
        }
        else
        {                           
            $stuff = stream_get_contents($fp);
            echo $stuff;
            $zip->close();                      
            if($stuff != null)
            {
                unlink($dir.$filename);
            }                       
        }
    }
    else
    {
        unlink($dir.$filename);
    }
```

Comment: It seems you don't understand "your" code: There are already several `unlink()`-calls.

Comment: because i dont know why it wont work so i placed a couple of them around hoping i would be able to determine which part isnt working, my separate code with ulink is working.

Comment: So `$file` and `$file1` are both the same filename but one has path info and then there's `$file_name` which is the same again bgut with an extension? You may want to pick more informative variable names. You're also hard-coding a variable `$file2` and then using it only once - Either call it something like `$IndexFilename` or just remove the variable...

Comment: $file2 is the file that i am searching inside the zip "$file1". well i already decided to just call a delete function when the user chooses close button for this.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't google this did ya?

Try [Unlink](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Edit:

Taking a look at this code, `$zip->open($file);` <-- is where you open the file.  The file variable is set by:

`"../mailtemplates/" . basename($_GET['tfilename'], '.' . $info['extension']) . '/' . "index.html"`

So you're grabbing a *relative* directory and grabbing a filename as a folder, and going to that folder **/index.html**.  Here's an example:

if you're in **c:\** testing and you go to ..**/mailtemplates/** you'll be in **c:\mailtemplates** and then you're looking at file **test**.php but you're *removing* the file extension, so you'll be opening the location **c:\mailtemplates\test\index.html**  so you open up that html file and read it.  Then, you're trying to *delete* **c:\mailtemplates\test.php**

can you explain how any of that makes sense to you? 'cause that seems very odd to me.

Comment: I dont' see code here that saves the file anywhere except in memory  If you're file is only in memory, then just null your variables or drop them out of scope.

Comment: do you mean this `$object->save_to_filename($localfile);` <-- because that is calling a separate function somewhere, and that's different from the file you're working with.

Comment: `function save_to_filename($filename)
    {
        $fp = @fopen($filename, "wb");
        if (!$fp) {
            throw new IOException("Could not open file for writing: ".$filename);
        }
        $result = $this->stream($fp);
        fclose($fp);
        return $result;
    }`